# Flutter firebase version solving failed in flutter 2.8.1

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, paystack

Because firebase_auth 0.16.0 depends on firebase_auth_web ^0.1.1 which depends on http_parser ^3.1.3, firebase_auth 0.16.0 requires http_parser ^3.1.3.
And because flutter_paystack >=1.0.5+1 depends on http ^0.13.1 which depends on http_parser ^4.0.0, firebase_auth 0.16.0 is incompatible with flutter_paystack >=1.0.5+1.
So, because flutter_sell_app depends on both firebase_auth 0.16.0 and flutter_paystack ^1.0.5+1, version solving failed.

My pubspec.yaml

```
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.0
  country_list_pick: ^1.0.1+2
  bottom_navy_bar: ^5.4.0
  cached_network_image: ^2.4.1
  carousel_slider: ^3.0.0
  flutter_html: 0.11.1
  flutter_rating_bar: ^3.2.0+1
  another_flushbar: ^1.10.10
  image_picker:
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.4+6
  carousel_pro: ^1.0.0
  flutter_staggered_animations: ^1.0.0
  flutter_credit_card: ^0.1.3
  mask_text_input_formatter: ^1.0.5
  progress_dialog: ^1.2.1
  rxdart: ^0.25.0
  # stripe_payment: ^1.1.4
  # flutter_facebook_login: ^3.0.0
  google_sign_in: ^4.5.1
  multi_image_picker: ^4.8.0
  flutter_absolute_path: 
    git:
      url: https://github.com/canewsin/flutter_absolute_path.git
  #path_provider: ^2.0.1
  fluttertoast: ^7.1.8
  flutter_staggered_grid_view: ^0.3.3
  transparent_image: ^1.0.0
  google_fonts:
  webview_flutter: ^2.0.2
  toast: ^0.1.5
  cloud_firestore: any
  firebase_auth: 0.16.0
  firebase_database: ^3.0.7
  firebase_storage: ^3.1.3
  firebase_messaging: 6.0.13
  photo_view: ^0.9.2
  place_picker:
  geolocator: ^5.1.5
  google_maps_flutter:
  permission_handler:
  timeago: ^2.0.26
  flutter_paystack: ^1.0.5+1
  sign_in_with_apple: ^3.0.0
  flutter_image_compress: ^1.0.0
  flutter_countdown_timer: ^4.1.0
  dio:
  flutter_datetime_picker: ^1.5.1
  maps_launcher: ^2.0.1
  readmore: ^2.1.0
  like_button: ^2.0.2
  clay_containers: ^0.3.2
  country_code_picker: ^2.0.2
```

Answer (score 2):

Please use the older version of flutter_paystack as ^1.0.5+1 version of ^1.0.5+1 depends on latest version of http_parser and firebase_auth: 0.16.0 depends on older version of http_parser. You can use ^1.0.0 or older version of flutter_paystack to solve your issue